# SQL order by date posted or date edited by the closest time to current

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to order by date edited or date posted.
For example if an item  date posted is 2018-03-16 20:40:00 and another item date edited is 2018-03-16 21:40:00 I want to show first the item that is closest time to current in date posted or date edited.

I tried this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date_posted DESC, date_edited DESC LIMIT 20"
```

However, if date_edited is higher time then in date_posted it shows that item (date_edited) and the rest of them after it not ordering by the time.

I also tried:

```
"ORDER BY date_posted DESC OR date_edited DESC..."
```

But that did not work at all.

So basically, I want to order it by the time from date_posted or date_edited to simplify it a little.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases support the `greatest()` function.  You can use:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
ORDER BY GREATEST(date_posted, date_edited) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

For those that don't you can emulate the logic easily using `CASE`.

Comment: Nah , didn't work. Is date("d-m-Y H:i:s") correct time in mysql because that is what im using when creating this posts with php.

Comment: Actually it worked i wrong typed something. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE WHEN date_posted > date_edited THEN date_posted
  ELSE date_edited
END AS sorting_date
FROM table 
ORDER BY sorting_date
```